# CentOS 7 : ip addresses in ifconfig and in network-script are different

Tags: centos, networking, internet, lan, networksetup

Given the CentOS server-like machine:

```
$ uname -a 
Linux labsm 3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Mar 7 19:03:37 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**EDIT**

My initial problem was that local network is Ok, but internet was not accessible. It appeared that my machine was blocked by mac-address. Now I get my mac-address in the list of the ones allowed internet access and everything is working.

However, I have one more question about the network. **The IP address in ifconfig doesn't match the one in the network-script**.

I did disable the NetworkManager and configure the network-script, so that the machine has the IP address `133.21.224.237`.
The network-script is:

```
{enp96s0f1}
$vi /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-Wired_connection_1

HWADDR=0C:C4:7A:F9:BA:CF
MACADDR=0C:C4:7A:F9:BA:CF
TYPE=Ethernet
PROXY_METHOD=none
BROWSER_ONLY=no
BOOTPROTO=none
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=no
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6_ADDR_GEN_MODE=stable-privacy
NAME=enp96s0f1
UUID=ef4dba55-7c9a-3d8e-94b6-5e2146284e1a
ONBOOT=yes
AUTOCONNECT_PRIORITY=-999
IPADDR=133.21.224.237
PREFIX=24
GATEWAY=133.21.224.94
DNS1=10.20.0.55
DNS2=10.20.0.56
PEERDNS=no
```

I did restart the network service with

```
$ systemctl restart network
```

But! In the ifconfig:

```
enp96s0f1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 133.21.224.29  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 133.21.224.255
        inet6 fe80::ec4:7aff:fef9:bacf  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 0c:c4:7a:f9:ba:cf  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 2186987  bytes 459109170 (437.8 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 423238  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 56064  bytes 6389505 (6.0 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

So, the line `inet 133.21.224.29` says that the ip address ends with 29, while I configured it 237 in the network-script. Even more interestingly, the machine can be accessed inside the local network by ssh **with both IP addresses**...

That IP address `133.21.224.29` was assigned to that machine some time before. But I don't understand how the machine receives it now, after I changed the network-script. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you working for Toyota in Japan?

Comment: The first odd thing I see (though I don't think it will break anything) is 3 network adaptors connected to the same network.

Comment: I am indeed working in Japan. All adaptors are on the same motherboard, that is a feature of it. So, I think they all should be connected to the same network. Anyway, I need only one, so if there is a way to disable others - tell me!

Comment: By the way, can you briefly tell me how do you know my location from the data I shared?

Comment: I was checking that you were not using someone else's (Toyota Japan) IP address (as this could cause network problems). You have multiple adaptors, so that you can connect them to different networks. To disable two of them, unplug them. I up-voted, and see no reason for a down-vote. By the way, do you have DHCP on your network, it will help a lot.

Comment: As I understand, they recently removed the DHCP from our network. But I will try to confirm if I am wrong. About my post, I see now that the admin has cutted some excessively funny, non informative parts of it.

Comment: Instead of using `ifconfig`, try using `ip addr show`. The `ifconfig` command is deprecated, and may not be showing all IP addresses on the interface.

Comment: Thank you @jeremy-dover for the tip! Indeed, in the `ip addr show` I see both addresses: `inet 133.21.224.29/24 brd 133.21.224.255 scope global enp96s0f1` and `inet 133.21.224.237/24 brd 133.21.224.255 scope global secondary enp96s0f1`. But how can I make the secondary one to be the only one? Or that is not a big deal?

Comment: It is probably safest to delete it. The command `ip addr del 133.21.224.29/24 dev enp96s0f1`, should suffice, but definitely check this syntax in the context of your environment.